# Layout xml naming convention format magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

Can u confirm if the layout xml file im using is of the proper format

routerfrontname_controllerfrontname_controlleraction.xml

Eg:

**routes.xml**

```
<router id="standard">
    <route id="something" frontName="s"/>
</router>
```

**Controller path**:

```
Controller/Result/Index.php
```

Then my layout file will be as :

s_result_index.xml?  Am I correct.

1) Can the "route id" and "frontName" be different?

2) If it is different too, then we use route frontname (ie 's' in my case).
Correct?

Answer (score 13):

Front name and route id can be different, but you should use id in file names.

Correct format is: `routeid_controllerfrontname_controlleraction.xml`

So it should be `something_result_index.xml`.

Comment: I think you meant to type `routeid` not `routerid`.

Comment: how about the camelCased controller action names, like: MyAction, that is converted to routerid_countrollerfrontname_my-action or routeid_countrollerfrontename_myaction ?

Comment: can frontname be front_name? what would be the layout name in this case?

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: How about if my router name as `fastsms/otpVerification/index/`? My layout name as `fastsms_otpVerification_index` but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
cms_page_view_id_yourpageurl.xml
```

this is for custom page made from backend and want to add css and js then create a file like above and insert your xml code into it.